# add multiple .csv files using bash command

Tags: shell-script

I want to iterate over all randomly generated CSV files in a folder using using bash and add them line by line. Each CSV files has 3 rows, the 1st row indicates just the number of generated files and may run from 1-50 and doesn't need to be included in the sum. There may be around 5 or 6 CSV files in the folder, it is randomly generated depending on the user input. The format of each CSV files looks like the following:

Node-1.csv

```
1 | 998749 | 39
2 | 989758 | 84 
3 | 1002785| 43 
4 | 997485 | 98 
5 | 996584 | 86 
6 | 1038453| 14
(continues... )
```

Node-2.csv

```
1 | 1098749| 49
2 | 899758 | 47 
3 | 992785 | 43 
4 | 1097458|98 
5 | 996584 |86 
6 | 998453| 14
(continues)
```

Node-3.csv

```
1 | 998999 | 40
2 | 989758 | 50 
3 | 1002785| 70 
4 | 997485 | 89 
5 | 1006584| 33 
6 | 989453 | 10
(continues)
```

the expected output is as follows

```
1 | 3096625
2 | 2879455
3 | 2998511
4 | 3092713
5 | 2999957
6 | 3026397
(continues...)
```

Basically, I want to sum up the contents of all the csv files in the folder,,,, the name of the csv files may be like: node-1.csv, node-2.csv, node-3.csv ...etc. The contents in each csc file is like the one i showed above... the 1st column is is the number that runs from 1-50 or more, the 2nd column is the local balance and 3rd column is the transaction. I want to add all the files line by line, i.e as the number run from 1-50, to know the total output/line

Comment: Can you please show your expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ideal task for AWK:

```
awk -F '|' \
    '    {results[$1+0]+=$2+$3} \
     END {for (i in results) \
              if (i != 0) \
                  print i" | "results[i]}' *.csv \
| sort --key=1 --field-separator='|' --numeric-sort
```

`-F '|'` means that lines will be split by pipe character, i.e. string `1 | 2 | 3` will be split into three fields: `1`, `2`, and `3`.

For each line, the following block is executed:

```
{results[$1+0]+=$2+$3}
```

`results` is an associative array. The index into this array is going to be the first field, for example, number 1. (We add zero to coerce the string into a number.) We then add the second and third fields and add the result to existing count for that particular value of field 1. (Initially, all cells in the array are zero.)

When all the lines are processed, the `END` block is executed. What it does is simply printing out the contents of the array, separating fields with pipe character. The `if` there filters out an entry that corresponds to all the empty lines in the input.

Finally, we sort the output (I assume you want that) by the first field, again using pipe as field delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, everything works correctly except the sorting ..., it doesn't sort the numbers correctly specially when csv files are more than 10.,,, I'm working with files which are may be more than 50

Comment: Ah! Use `--numeric-sort`. I'll amend the answer to include that.